# Verify SHA-1 signature using OpenSSL with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl

I tried it for more than one day but still can't get this to work.

I am trying to verify a XML file using a RSA signature. I got this to work in a C# dotNET application but I need to get this to work in C++ without dotNET.

Somehow I can't get the signature to be verified in my program. On a openssl command line it works just fine. Please give me a hint as to what I might be missing. Thanks!

Here is what I have so far:

HelloData.txt :

```
Hello
```

HalloSignHash.sha1 :

```
k„“D⁄�.‡f�*÷?5¶¥;È›h„ëßÚœ¨YNº‚Â1)îZ6›?@6©ØÍØC˛¨IblˇVt„N¥df!ˆn’”ø>±∏p*Öîhäå1ô∆:V‹
ßáJ†ÉY¶V+6ö\ìÒÜ…&~¥∑&º8ó<T„
```

key.pub :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCDrL6sGxBjjeb6eVdDNQtKFZw5
K0VGAOdOlCFnIo7puazkeTKJ8TY7a0KG3fcFWXLoyxNAvocZLvQTmX2pSfl28XWq
TL3kgzouYJzVdbG1mX7B/LqQAlfhuzIJyqPK+C0uYkIESvJRDWqN2nji9oIb179u
Y2YYQRGMrmF/FxDZvwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

openssl:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify TestCert.pem -signature HalloSignHash.sha1 HelloData.txt

openssl dgst -sha1 -verify key.pub -signature HalloSignHash.sha1 HelloData.txt

Verified OK
```

OpenSSLCryptoSample.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "osslcrypto.h"

#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>

#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>

#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


#define MAX_LEN 256


//----------------------------------------------------------------------


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//
// Local variables definition
//
const char      cert_filestr[] = "./TestCert.pem";
EVP_PKEY*       evpkey = NULL;
BIO*            certbio = NULL;
X509*           cert = NULL;
EVP_MD_CTX*     ctx = NULL;
unsigned char   sigBuf[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
char            msg[] = "Hello";
int             bufSize = sizeof(msg);
int             ret = 1;
int             bytesRet = 0;

OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();


//
//  These function calls initialize openssl for correct work
//
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();


//
//  Create the Input/Output BIO's
//
certbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());


//
// Loading the certificate from file (PEM)
//
ret = BIO_read_filename(certbio, cert_filestr);
cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(certbio, NULL, 0, NULL);

if (NULL == cert)
{
    printf("Error loading cert from the .pem file!\n");
} // if
else
{
    printf("Certificate loaded from the .pem file\n\n");
}


//
// Extract the certificate's public key data
//
evpkey = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
if (NULL == evpkey)
{
    printf("Error getting public key from certificate\n");
} // if
else
{
    printf("Public key extracted from the certificate\n\n");
}


//
// Read signed HASH from file

FILE * pFile;
long lSize;
char * buffer;
size_t result;

pFile = fopen("Test", "rb");
if (pFile == NULL) { fputs("File error", stderr); exit(1); }

// obtain file size:
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
if (buffer == NULL) { fputs("Memory error", stderr); exit(2); }

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);
if (result != lSize) { fputs("Reading error", stderr); exit(3); }

/* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */
for (size_t i = 0; i < lSize; i++)
{
    sigBuf[i] = buffer[i];
}
bytesRet = lSize;

// terminate
fclose(pFile);
free(buffer);

// Print signature buffer
printf("Data in the signed buffer is : %s\n\n", sigBuf);


//
// Allocating memory for EVP_MD_CTX Context object
//
ctx = (EVP_MD_CTX *)malloc(sizeof(EVP_MD_CTX));
if (NULL == ctx)
{
    printf("Memory is not allocated for EVP_MD_CTX object\n");
} // if
else
{
    printf("Memory allocated for EVP_MD_CTX object\n\n");
}


//
// Initializing EVP_MD_CTX Context object
EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx);


//
// Calling EVP_VerifyInit_ex() function to initialize context
// for verification
//
EVP_VerifyInit_ex(ctx, EVP_sha1(), NULL);


//
// After initializing the context, the signed data to be verified
// is fed into context. This is done with EVP_VerifyUpdate() function
//
EVP_VerifyUpdate(ctx, msg, sizeof(msg));


//
// Performing the actual verification of the signature using
// EVP_VerifyFinal() function
//
ret = EVP_VerifyFinal(ctx, sigBuf, bytesRet, evpkey);
if (0 == ret)
{
    printf("Signature doesn't match\n\n");
} // if
else
{
    printf("Signature verified successfully\n\n");
}

printf("Press RETURN to quit!\n\n");


getchar();

return 0;

}
```

All I ever get is:

```
"Signature doesn't match"
```

What am I doing wrong? Please Help!

Comment: How about changing your `EVP_VerifyInit_ex` to `EVP_VerifyInit` ? Another thing is, why use C `malloc` and not OpenSSL new like `EVP_MD_CTX_new` ? Plus, the last statement, `if (0 == ret)` is incorrect, as the function `EVP_VerifyFinal` returns 0 for bad signature and -1 for other errors. Thus you may have broken signature (somehow) and still get positive verification.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue until I switched over to using the public certificate (-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----) instead of the public key. Mine was actually failing when trying to read the certificate in PEM_read_bio_X509.

Looks like in most cases your program is continuing after an error occurs. Might look at adding returns to kill the program on error events, might prevent errors from slipping through unnoticed.